# Save all the inputs text of a list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

i have a code of a list in html. i used in the code the local storage to save the add or eliminate items of the list. for that the code works perfectly. Inside of each item of the list, if you click on it, its a input text but when i save the list in local storage i need to save also the text that are inside each input text. I need save when the text in the input text is changed. How can i save all the input texts of the list??

here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/juank_romero/hA8Ps/16/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#list1").listview("refresh");
if (localStorage["K"] != null) {
  var contentsOfOldDiv = jQuery.parseJSON(localStorage["K"]);    
  $("#list1").html(contentsOfOldDiv);
 } 
});

$(document).on("click", ".fila", function () {
$(this).next().next(".cuadro").slideToggle();
});

$(document).on("change", ".ref", function () {//here i need to save all the input´s text
 $("#prueba").text("refresh");
localStorage["K"] = JSON.stringify($("#list1").html());
});

$(document).on("click", ".borrar", function () {
$(this).parent("li").remove();
$("#list1").listview("refresh");
localStorage["K"] = JSON.stringify($("#list1").html());


});
$(document).on("click", "#btn2", function () {
var content =
    "<li>" +
    "<a href='#' class='fila'>elemento1</a><a href='#' data-icon='delete' class='borrar'>Favorita</a><div class='cuadro'><label>label:</label><input type='text' value='' maxlength='3' class='ref'/><label >label2:</label><select data-role='slider'><option value='off'>Off</option><option value='on'>On</option></select></div>" +
    "</li>";

$(content).appendTo("#list1").enhanceWithin();
$("#list1").listview("refresh");
localStorage["K"] = JSON.stringify($("#list1").html());



});
```

thanks.

Comment: What are you getting in localStorage["K"] from '$(document).on("click", ".borrar", function () {
$(this).parent("li").remove();
$("#list1").listview("refresh");
localStorage["K"] = JSON.stringify($("#list1").html());'

Comment: I saved the changes in the list when i add or in this case when i remove items from the list. So localStorage["K"] has saved the list. In the link you can find the demo code.